# Test Flight app will not install "waiting"

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, installation

I am using Test Flight for the first time and am having trouble during the install step on my iPhone 5C (running 8.0.2, code from Xcode 6).  The provision profile is set up with this phone UDID and the test flight configuration profile is installed on my phone.  I am able to create the app on Test Flight and upload my Ad Hoc builds easily and I grant permission to this device.  I then can access the app through Test Flight on my phone where I click the green install button.  The app icon then pops up on my device displaying "waiting" below the icon....forever.  It never installs.... I have been trying to do it over my cell network (with all LTE bars) so maybe it requires wifi?  The app is only 212MB and I have 1.4GB of storage on my phone.

Also I am unable to download the Test Flight SDK for some reason, but I wouldn't expect that this is the root of my issues...

I have tried the following:
-Restart phone
-Delete app in waiting stage and re-install
-Delete app from Test Flight and create new one with different bundle ID (matching the one in Xcode)
-Upload a second build and try to install that one

After trying all of these I am beginning to think I will have to try later when I have access to wifi and it will solve my issue.  In the meantime....any suggestions??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: TestFlight SDK isn't necessary now. First of all try to install your .ipa via iTunes. Just add it to Apps and do sync. If it wont be successful the problem might be in provision file.

Comment: Just a note: Apple recently purchased TestFlight and integrated it into iOS 8. You can see more information at the link below. There is a video tutorial that is really helpful. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you both for the quick replies.  I will let you know what works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks dfmuir.  I recommend downloading the TestFlight as dfmuir states above.  This works very well for beta testing and you do not need UDID, just the other users' Apple ID emails.  Works seamlessly, as long as you have wifi for your devices when downloading the app.